# How do I go about making this Conways Life program in java

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I am making a Conway's Game of Life program in java, and am trying to change it from the command line version to a GUI. From the command line I just printed an array which showed the generations (the objects such as blocks and blinkers are shown as a series of 1's and 0's where it is blank, and in the GUI I'm showing it as squares (white squares as blank and blue squares where it isn't). But where I'm getting stuck is when I make another method (which replaces the method which prints the array) which checks the grid array, if there is a zero then the square changes from white to blue, and vice-versa. The Conway's Life rules are dealt with in a separate class which is independent, and all this method does is after the rules have changed the array this method checks it.

The rules are done in methods in one class and the GUI components are done in another. But since I need instance of both how would I go about doing it?, merge the two classes (all the GUI classes into the Life one, embed them some how, I am completely stuck on what to do

```
public void runGUI() {
    int x = getX(), y = getY();

    x /= squareSize;
    y /= squareSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < LifeData.grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < LifeData.grid[i].length; j++) {
            if (LifeData.grid[i][j] == 0)
                l.setCell(x, y, l.getCell(x, y) + 1);
            else
                l.setCell(x, y, l.getCell(x, y) - 1);
            this.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

That is what I have changed it to now but when compiling it is saying "non-static variable `grid` cannot be referenced from a static context" and "non-static method `runGUI()` cannot be referenced from a static context". When trying to run the method.

Comment: Can you not just pass the array to your GUI and then read it while drawing? Or have a getter on the Rules class to get the array and then you have access to it in your GUI class.

Comment: Post some of the code you have thus far and we might be able to better point you in the right direction. It sounds like you are going the right way, but just getting stuck on how to get info to the GUI layer.

Comment: How could I pass the array to the GUI, the array being used is in one class, do I do something like classname.arrayname to point to the array in use?

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate thread that will execute the game of life and update the GUI.

Something like this

```
public class GameExecutor implements Runnable {

  private static final int DELAY = 1000;

  private GameOfLife game;
  private boolean stop = false;
  private Gui gui;

  public GameExecutor(Gui gui, GameOfLife game) {
    this.gui = gui;
    this.game = game;
  };

  public void run(){
    game.start();

    while (!stop) {
      game.step(); //execute a step
      gui.update(game.getState());
      try {
        Thread.sleep(DELAY);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
  }

}
```

Launch this in a thread at startup and pass it your gui.  Don't forget to update the gui in the correct Swing thread.

Obviously you'll need to add some code to stop it, too :)